# Querying XML with Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, netbeans

I'm able to run simple queries on my XML document using Java, but I'm looking to run a more 'advanced' query and have run into a bit of trouble in doing so.

I am able to get the name of only the first actor of this example (in this case Marlon Brando), when I want to get the names of the rest of the actors in the XML file.

I have used so far `/film/cast` which shows me all of the actor names, but also the role they play within the film; which I do not want.

Please help! 
Thanks

XMl:

```
    <!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<film>
    <title>"Godfather, The"</title>
    <year>1972</year>
    <directors>
        <director>Francis Ford Coppola</director>
    </directors>
    <genres>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
    </genres>
    <plot>Son of a mafia boss takes over when his father is critically wounded in a mob hit.</plot>
    <cast>
        <performer>
            <actor>Marlon Brando</actor>
            <role>Don Vito Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Al Pacino</actor>
            <role>Michael Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Diane Keaton</actor>
            <role>Kay Adams Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Robert Duvall</actor>
            <role>Tom Hagen</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>James Caan</actor>
            <role>Sonny Corleone</role>
        </performer>
    </cast>
</film>
```

Java class:

```
pa

ckage Film;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ASS2_FILM{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream (new File("/Users/benchalmers/Documents/Uni /Year 2/Database Engineering/Assignment 3/Film/FILM.xml"));

            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String expression3 = "/film/cast/";
            System.out.println(expression3);
            String actor = xPath.compile(expression3).evaluate(xmlDocument);
            System.out.println(actor);
```

Returned value:

```
/film/cast


            Marlon Brando
            Don Vito Corleone


            Al Pacino
            Michael Corleone


            Diane Keaton
            Kay Adams Corleone


            Robert Duvall
            Tom Hagen


            James Caan
            Sonny Corleone
```

Answer (score 1):

To get actor names only try to change from:

```
String expression3 = "/film/cast/";
```

To:

```
String expression3 = "/film/cast/performer/actor";
```